# Equivalence relation that has 2 different classes of equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Give an example of an equivalence relation defined on the set A={0,1,2,3,4} which has two different classes of equivalence.

I think I don't understand this topic, but i created something like this:

(0,0) (0,1) (1,0) (1,1) (0,2) (2,0) (2,2) (1,2) (2,1) and (3,3) (3,4) (4,3) (4,4)
so equivalence class of 0 is: [0]={(0,0),(0,1),(0,2)} and [1]={(1,0),(1,2),(1,1)}, [3]={(3,3),(3,4)}, [4]={(4,3),(4,4)} and what now? is it ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relation is fine but you might have a misconception about the definition of an equivalence class.

The definition of an equivalence class $[a]$ for a relation $S$ is given by,
$$ [a] = \{x\space|\space x\space S \space a\}$$

Therefore, for the example you gave, the equivalence classes would be as follows,
$$ [0] = \{0,1,2\}$$
$$ [1] = \{0,1,2\}$$
$$ [2] = \{0,1,2\}$$
$$ [3] = \{3,4\}$$
$$ [4] = \{3,4\}$$

And the distinct classes would be $[0] = [1] = [2]$  and $[3] = [4]$

Comment: so this one has 5 classes of equivalence, but only 2 different classes?

in the class we should list all the elements from the relation?
like for [0]={all unique elements form (0,0),(0,1),(0,2)}

Comment: Yes, there are 5 equivalence classes but only 2 DISTINCT ones. In general, if the set that your relation acts on has $n$ elements, there will be $n$ equivalence classes. However, we cannot tell how many distinct ones there will be.

Comment: For the 2nd question, yes as well. As long as $n\spaceS\spacea$, then $n\element[a]$

Comment: Sorry, my TeX had some mistakes. As long as $n S a$, then $n\in[a]$

Comment: thanks for your help :D
One more question if we set our relation to mod(2), there will be only 2 equivalence classes and these 2 classes will be distinct. [0]={0,2,4} and [1]={1,3}

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand your relation. Under what conditions is $x$ related to $y$?

Comment: Relation is an equivalence relation when R is symmetric, transitive and reflexive. So you are asking about the first one? Honestly I don't know, how x is related to y. I'm quite new at this. Is it possible to make a relation which classes will be a%2?  for a=0->0, a=1->1, a=2->0, a=3->1, a=4->0 that will fit to this task with 2 distinct classes?

Comment: Based on your description, I believe you are trying to define a relation in the following manner: $S = \{(x,y)| x\equivy (mod 2)\}$ which I believe should satisfy your requirements

Comment: Sorry still new at using TeX formatting $S = \{(x,y)| x \equiv y (mod 2)\}$

Comment: Yes, that's probably what i meant. Again, thanks for your help.